# Error: Function name must be a string with Closure callback

Tags: php, laravel, callback

I'm trying to write a function with a callback function.
This is my function with callback

```php
    public function functionWithCallback($field, $value, Closure $callback = null)
    {
        $adminIds = Admin::when(!$callback, function ($query) use ($field, $value) {
                $query->where($field, $value);
            })->when($callback, $callback($query)) /* Error on this line */
            ->get()->pluck('id')->toArray();
    }
```

And this is function which call to function has callback in parameter

```php
    public function functionCallToCallback()
    {
        $this->functionWithCallback('id', 1);
    }

    public function functionCallToCallback2()
    {
        $this->functionWithCallback('name', 'Test', function ($query) use ($value) {
            $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . $value . '%');
        });
    }
```

When I run this code, it thrown an exception

```php
Error: Function name must be a string
```

The error thrown in line which contain this code `when($callback, $callback($query))`. But when I comment function `functionCallToCallback`, it thrown an another error:

```php
ErrorException: Undefined variable: query
```

Anyone know how to solve this? Thanks

Comment: For the first error you are not passing a string for the second param: `$this->functionWithCallback('id', 1);`

Comment: the 3rd argument to `when` is a default callback to use, btw

Comment: @GetSet the 2nd param is just a normal param. It can be anything

Comment: If it can be anything, why is the error explicitly: `Error: Function name must be a string`? ... `$callback` is your 2nd param, yet you call it by defining it as `1`.

Comment: My bad, I read that wrong, @simpsons3

Comment: @GetSet but ```$callback``` is the 3rd param

Comment: Ok, I read that wrong. However it is still the same problem. You default your 3rd param `$callback` to `null` and `null` of course is not a string. There's the error. You need to supply a 3rd param. Or as @lagbox suggests, have a default callback.

Comment: @GetSet I reference code in laravel framwork source code. In ```https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Auth/Passwords/PasswordBroker.php```, function ```reset``` written the same way and I used in my code, it worked. But in my code it don't, is there any way to explain this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling the callback instead of passing the callback to `when`:

```
when($callback, $callback($query))
```

The second argument to `when` is a callback:

```
when($callback, $callback)
```

Though you shouldn't need this extra call to `when` since you can pass both the callbacks to the call to `when`:

```
$adminIds = Admin::when($callback, $callback, function ($query) use ($field, $value) { ... })
    ->pluck('id')->toArray();
```

> "You may pass another closure as the third argument to the `when` method. This closure will only execute if the first argument evaluates as `false`."

Side Note: not sure where `$value` comes from in `functionCallToCallback2`

Comment: I want to separate it because I want to write some function call to ``` functionWithCallback``` function, like ```functionCallToCallback3```, ```functionCallToCallback4```,... And each function can have different way to query data which can be written in ```$callback```.

Comment: @simpsons3 That's fine, you can keep the `when`s separated, but the rest of the answer stands. Your issue is that in your `when()` call, you're executing the callback and passing the returned result (`null`) in as the second parameter. You need to pass in the callback function itself as the second parameter.

Comment: ahh, I've misunderstood your idea. I just have read ```when``` function in source code and change my code like yours. It worked! Thanks